# React-Admin notify message on custom form

Tags: react-admin

I have recently started using react-admin and encountered to problem with notify.
Added Custom route for registration, noLayout property,  expected notify to show me message when something happens.
Notify does not display message on the screen. It works in some other pages that are not custom.
If someone knows what is the problem here, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

When a route doesn't use the Layout, it opt out for everything the Layout supports, including showing notifications.

You have to include the `<Notification />` component in your custom page component and it will work.